# response = 0,through Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Im trying to make POST Retrofit response,but I must to have data from this response.In stack tace I saw that request is OK and code==200,but response =0.But this request must give me data,I checked this from Postman service.How can I get data from my request?

**stack trace with fragment and result from Postman:**

```
 response = {Response@830025479464} 
     body = {SignInResults@830025477808} 
      signInResult = null
      signInResults = null
     errorBody = null
     rawResponse = {Response@830025473584} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create}"
      body = {OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody@830025471872} 
      cacheControl = null
      cacheResponse = null
      request = {Request@830024580584} "Request{method=POST, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create, tag=Request{method=POST, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create, tag=null}}"
      handshake = {Handshake@830025421608} 
      headers = {Headers@830025472832} "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Content-Length,Authorization,AccessToken\nAccess-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nContent-Type: application/json\nDate: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 11:16:04 GMT\nServer: nginx\nSet-Cookie: rid=bbf4159793d4402caf449f8eeabe0404; expires=Sat, 17-May-2031 01:48:34 GMT; Max-Age=475079550; path=/; domain=vid.me\nSet-Cookie: srid=QYpbrONRvejA7DiwZIYTg-dgf8Ug-JBPIKnJL9u7coLmkK585aPsQyY; expires=Sat, 17-May-2031 01:48:34 GMT; Max-Age=475079550; path=/; domain=vid.me\nSet-Cookie: vmtoken=418bdb0823fd49729a51a6d82baf8521; expires=Wed, 26-Apr-2017 11:16:04 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=vid.me; secure\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains\nVary: Accept-Encoding\nX-Request-Time: 87\nX-Vidme-Authorization-Okay: false\nX-Vidme-Server-Id: 9610996701283818874f67e619e7c6ef\ntransfer-encoding: chunked\nConn"
      message = "OK"
      networkResponse = {Response@830025461696} "Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://api.vid.me/auth/create}"
      priorResponse = null
      protocol = {Protocol@830023792880} "http/1.1"
      code = 200
```

**Result from Postman:**

```
  {
        "status": true,
        "auth": {
            "token": "12f6d4123b9947e79f37a4c415bb4b51",
            "expires": "2017-04-26 10:38:05",
            "user_id": "11272862"
        },
        "user": {
            "user_id": "11272862",
            "username": "prozrostyslav",
            "full_url": "https://vid.me/prozrostyslav",
            "avatar": null,
            "avatar_url": "https://d2ha22j8ys3e0o.cloudfront.net/images/default-avatars/13.png?602-2-2-4-9",
            "cover": null,
            "cover_url": "https://d2ha22j8ys3e0o.cloudfront.net/images/default-covers/03.jpg?602-2-2-4-9",
            "displayname": null,
            "follower_count": 0,
            "likes_count": "0",
            "video_count": 0,
            "video_views": "0",
            "videos_scores": 0,
            "comments_scores": 0,
            "bio": null
        }
    }
```

**my fragment:**

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    Button btnLogin;

    public List<SignInResult> signInResult;
    String username_value,password_value;
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me/";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        username = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_field);
        password = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        btnLogin = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Authorize();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void Authorize() {
        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        final VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);

         username_value = username.getText().toString();
         password_value = password.getText().toString();
String basicauth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(String.format("%s:%s",username_value,password_value).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Call<SignInResults> call = videoApi.insertUser(username_value,password_value);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SignInResults>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignInResults> call, Response<SignInResults> response) {
              int i = response.body().signInResult.getUser_id();
                Log.d("Response ==>> ", String.valueOf(i));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignInResults> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
}
}
```

**SignInResult:**

```
public class SignInResult {


    @SerializedName("authorization")
    @Expose
    private String authorization;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer user_id;
    public Integer getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }


}
```

**SignInResults:**

```
public class SignInResults {
    public SignInResult signInResult;

    public List<SignInResult> getSignInResults() {
        return signInResults;
    }

    List<SignInResult> signInResults;
}
```

**API interface:**

```
 public interface VideoApi {

        @GET("/videos/featured")
        Call<Videos> getFeaturedVideo();

        @GET("/videos/new")
        Call<Videos> getNewVideo();

    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/auth/create")
       Call<SignInResults>insertUser(@Field("username") String username,
                               @Field("password") String password
                               );
    }
```

**Error(when I try to get value in onResponse):**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.vid_me_app.FeedFragment$2.onResponse(FeedFragment.java:69)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to check the structure of your json like in your main object there are 2 json objects and status boolean. that means your main object contain 2 models (one is user and second is auth) and boolean.

```
package com.ramesh.myapplication.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by Ramesh on 4/26/2016.
 */
public class SignInResult {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private Boolean status;
    @SerializedName("auth")
    private Auth auth;
    @SerializedName("user")
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Auth getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public void setAuth(Auth auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    public static class User {
        @SerializedName("user_id")
        private String userId;
        @SerializedName("username")

        private String username;
        @SerializedName("full_url")
        private String fullUrl;
        @SerializedName("avatar")
        private String avatar;
        @SerializedName("avatar_url")
        private String avatarUrl;
        @SerializedName("cover")
        private String cover;
        @SerializedName("cover_url")
        private String coverUrl;
        @SerializedName("displayname")
        private String displayname;
        @SerializedName("follower_count")
        private Integer followerCount;
        @SerializedName("likes_count")
        private String likesCount;
        @SerializedName("video_count")
        private Integer videoCount;
        @SerializedName("video_views")
        private String videoViews;
        @SerializedName("videos_scores")
        private Integer videosScores;
        @SerializedName("comments_scores")
        private Integer commentsScores;
        @SerializedName("bio")
        private String bio;

        public String getBio() {
            return bio;
        }

        public void setBio(String bio) {
            this.bio = bio;
        }

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getFullUrl() {
            return fullUrl;
        }

        public void setFullUrl(String fullUrl) {
            this.fullUrl = fullUrl;
        }

        public String getAvatar() {
            return avatar;
        }

        public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
            this.avatar = avatar;
        }

        public String getAvatarUrl() {
            return avatarUrl;
        }

        public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
            this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
        }

        public String getCover() {
            return cover;
        }

        public void setCover(String cover) {
            this.cover = cover;
        }

        public String getCoverUrl() {
            return coverUrl;
        }

        public void setCoverUrl(String coverUrl) {
            this.coverUrl = coverUrl;
        }

        public String getDisplayname() {
            return displayname;
        }

        public void setDisplayname(String displayname) {
            this.displayname = displayname;
        }

        public Integer getFollowerCount() {
            return followerCount;
        }

        public void setFollowerCount(Integer followerCount) {
            this.followerCount = followerCount;
        }

        public String getLikesCount() {
            return likesCount;
        }

        public void setLikesCount(String likesCount) {
            this.likesCount = likesCount;
        }

        public Integer getVideoCount() {
            return videoCount;
        }

        public void setVideoCount(Integer videoCount) {
            this.videoCount = videoCount;
        }

        public String getVideoViews() {
            return videoViews;
        }

        public void setVideoViews(String videoViews) {
            this.videoViews = videoViews;
        }

        public Integer getVideosScores() {
            return videosScores;
        }

        public void setVideosScores(Integer videosScores) {
            this.videosScores = videosScores;
        }

        public Integer getCommentsScores() {
            return commentsScores;
        }

        public void setCommentsScores(Integer commentsScores) {
            this.commentsScores = commentsScores;
        }
    }

    public static class Auth {

        @SerializedName("token")
        private String token;
        @SerializedName("expires")
        private String expires;
        @SerializedName("user_id")
        private String userId;

        public String getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        public void setToken(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }

        public String getExpires() {
            return expires;
        }

        public void setExpires(String expires) {
            this.expires = expires;
        }

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }
    }
}
```

I have made one class and other subclasses you can change it to independent classes as you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you,but how can I have,for example,status and code in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse a `SignInResults` object from the response body. But looking at the postman response, this has nothing to do with.

You must parse an object corresponding to:

```
 {
    "status": true,
    "auth": {
        "token": "12f6d4123b9947e79f37a4c415bb4b51",
        "expires": "2017-04-26 10:38:05",
        "user_id": "11272862"
    },
    "user": {
        "user_id": "11272862",
        "username": "prozrostyslav",
        "full_url": "https://vid.me/prozrostyslav",
        "avatar": null,
        "avatar_url": "https://d2ha22j8ys3e0o.cloudfront.net/images/default-avatars/13.png?602-2-2-4-9",
        "cover": null,
        "cover_url": "https://d2ha22j8ys3e0o.cloudfront.net/images/default-covers/03.jpg?602-2-2-4-9",
        "displayname": null,
        "follower_count": 0,
        "likes_count": "0",
        "video_count": 0,
        "video_views": "0",
        "videos_scores": 0,
        "comments_scores": 0,
        "bio": null
    }
}
```